# API to get "total token left" of a custom token

Tags: tokens, ico, external-api

If let say we launch a ICO using Ethereum blockchain, how can I check for total token left in the market?

The typical workflow will be like:

1. Investor send *n* ETH to my wallet
2. System will verify the amount of ETH sent by investor
3. System send custom token *(XXX)* to investor
4. System display total token left on the website

Any API that can get the XXX token left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this api for simple ERC-TOKEN

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055

Change contract address on link to your contract address

left tokens in market is (Total token for sale as crowedsale)-(value of array result)/(10^(Token Decimals of your token))

I hope this helpful

Comment: I tried with `0x4355fC160f74328f9b383dF2EC589bB3dFd82Ba0` this address _(Opus foundation)_, but the total supply is different from what they claimed _(1600 mil)_

Comment: Token Decimals: 18

Comment: Opus foundation : 


Contract address:0x4355fC160f74328f9b383dF2EC589bB3dFd82Ba0 


Token Decimals: 18


total supply 1600mil for sale 900mil


in this case we need number token for sale


900mil-((724031315437989207411571392)/(10^18)= 900000000-724031315=175968685


number token left =175968685